# JAX-RS URI matching in regex

Tags: regex, jax-rs

I'm trying to match a specific path element in a URI.  I have two different URI types:

```
/aaa/bbb/ccc?param2=x,param2=y
```

and:

```
/_Vddd/aaa/bbb/ccc?param2=x,param2=y
```

I want to always collect the whole string, except for in the second case, when I want to collect everything after the `/_Vddd`

NOTE: `ddd` can be anything.

BTW: this is being used in JAX-RS path statements.  I'm trying to use non-capturning groups, but can't get it to match.  For some reason:

`/{path:(?:(/_V[^/]*))?/.*}` is only matching when the URI includes the `/_Vddd`, and return the `/_Vddd` as part of the path variable.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is not how non-capturing groups work. They are still included in the match (plus, you have an unnecessary capturing group inside your non-capturing group). Only lookarounds are left out from the match, but Java does not support variable-length lookbehinds. So if you cannot use the result from a capturing group (and use it the other way round) this won't be possible: `(?:/_V[^/]*)?(/.*)` Now your desired path is in capture number `1`. However, I have no idea why yours doesn't work when `/_Vddd` isn't there at all (and my regex won't solve it)